# Testing an iOS app using Appium without paid Developer account

Tags: iphone, applications, quality

I am very new to iOS - I am an android person, and I have been given an app to test which is already installed in our iphone. I am using appium as a testing tool. Is it required for me to have a developer account - paid - just to be able to test apps on a real device?

Comment: On a slightly separate note - have you any experience with using Appium? I tried to use it for a university project, but I couldn’t figure out how to use it at all.

Comment: I don't really have that much experience aside from using it on Android testing. It is so much easier to set it up on windows and android. But since I have more experience in Selenium, this is the reason why I took Appium to be my test tool.

Comment: ah you might be ok so. I use selenium quite a bit myself, I just found Appium to be very confusing to set up. Good luck with the project :)

Comment: It is confusing. But I don't know anymore what to use :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the rules of Appium, or if it's relevant to this question, but you don't need a paid developer account to test on a real device.  You can develop apps and deploy them to your own real device, for example, without paying Apple.

You only need a paid account if you want the app in the App Store or deployed in any enterprise program.)

Per [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/):

> If you’re looking to develop apps for Apple platforms, download the
>   Xcode developer tools, SDKs, and resources for free on the downloads
>   page. **Program membership is not required**. If you don’t already
>   have an Apple ID, you can create one here.
>
> **Apple Developer Program**.
>   If you’re an individual or sole proprietor/single person business interested in creating apps for distribution on the App Store
>   for iPhone, iPad, Mac, and Apple Watch, enroll in the Apple Developer
>   Program. Membership includes access to beta OS releases, advanced app
>   capabilities, and tools to develop, test, and distribute apps and
>   Safari extensions. Developers enrolled as individuals will sell apps
>   on the App Store using their personal name.